# Fitting blocks into an asymmetrical shape (Python, Genetic Algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, genetic

Hi I'm trying to fit Lego Blocks into an asymmetrical shape.

The shape looks like this:
[image]

I can choose between all Lego blocks (different weights) which are:

- 8x2 (0.35)
- 8x1 (0.29)
- 6x2 (0.28)
- 6x1 (0.25)
- and so on

all the bricks can be align vertically and horicontally

to bring the shape into code I use an Array like:

```
  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I now need to fit the blocks into this shape with the lowest cost
I think about using genetic algorithm for this, but not sure actually how to start

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have an infinite stock of every block type? Do you have 1x1 blocks?

Comment: I guess "lowest cost" means "lowest total weight"?

Comment: @Olivier yes infinte stock of every block type 
and yes lowest total weight

Answer (score 0):

For start, you can limit the possible coordinates only to the interior squares by maintaining a precomputed coordinate array and using it as part of DNA. If the interior area is only half of total area, it should have at least 100% more performance.

Then the DNA can be made of the following genes:

- type or index of type of lego
- rotation of lego
- translation of lego --> maps to interior-squares array

then the fitness can be computed by:

- for all legos placed:
- - penalty += `a1 * (each square of lego that overlaps with other lego)^2`
- - penalty += `a2 * (each square of lego that overflows the shape)^2`
- - penalty += `a3 * (cost of a lego)^2`
- finally:
- - fitness = `(a4 * the percentage of interior filled) - penalty`